# Remove an elements from the string if it contains a stopwords

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have a list as below:

```
lst = ['for Sam', 'Just in', 'Mark Rich']
```

I am trying to remove an element from list of strings(string contains one or more words) which contains `stopwords`.

As 1st and 2nd elements in the list contains `for` and `in` which are `stopwords`, it will return

```
new_lst = ['Mark Rich']
```

**What I tried**

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

lst = ['for Sam', 'Just in', 'Mark Rich']
new_lst = [i.split(" ") for i in lst]
new_lst = [" ".join(i) for i in new_lst for j in i if j not in stop_words]
```

Which is giving me output as:

```
['for Sam', 'Just in', 'Mark Rich', 'Mark Rich']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `if` statement rather than extra nesting:

```
new_lst = [' '.join(i) for i in new_lst if not any(j in i for j in stop_words)]
```

If you wish to utilize `set`, you can use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
new_lst = [' '.join(i) for i in new_lst if stop_words.isdisjoint(i)]
```

---

Here's a demonstration:

```
stop_words = {'for', 'in'}

lst = ['for Sam', 'Just in', 'Mark Rich']
new_lst = [i.split() for i in lst]
new_lst = [' '.join(i) for i in new_lst if stop_words.isdisjoint(i)]

print(new_lst)

# ['Mark Rich']
```

Comment: Your 1st answer worked like a charm but 2nd one is giving an empty list.

Comment: @Sociopath, Nope, works fine, see my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and use `sets` to check if any words within the two lists intersect:

```
[i for i in lst if not set(stop_words) & set(i.split(' '))]
['Mark Rich']]
```

Comment: thanks. Worked like a charm. Only one thing, in your answer you misplaced `]`

Comment: Note `set.intersection` has higher complexity vs `set.disjoint`. It's not necessary to calculate the exact intersection of the 2 sets to know if the intersection is empty.

Comment: Yes I actually thought about `.isdisjoint` right when i saw your answer. thx for clarifying